# How to set in a custom validatior a generic method

Tags: c#, validation, properties, customvalidator

I create a `Custom Validator` to my `Response` property. Here is the code

```
public partial class MultipleSelectionQuestion<T> : Question
{
    private ICollection<T> _response;

    public int? MaxSelections
    {
        get { return ((MultipleSelectionQuestionTemplate<T>)this.QuestionTemplate).MaxSelections; }
    }

    public ICollection<T> Range
    {
        get { return ((MultipleSelectionQuestionTemplate<T>)this.QuestionTemplate).Range; }
    }

    [CustomValidation(typeof(CommonValidation), "ValidationMultipleSelectionResponseChoices")]
    [Required]
    public ICollection<T> Response
    {
        get { return _response; }
        set {  SetProperty(ref _response, value, "Response"); }
    }
}
```

And here is my `CommonValidation` static class, and I realized that `Response` property does not find the method. The problem is the generic.

```
public static class CommonValidation
{
    public static ValidationResult ValidationMultipleSelectionResponseChoices<T>(IEnumerable<T> value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var question = (MultipleSelectionQuestion<T>)context.ObjectInstance;
        if (value != null)
        {
            var maxSelections = question.MaxSelections;

            if (maxSelections.HasValue)
            {
                if (value.Count() > maxSelections.Value)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(
                        string.Format(
                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                            "Response must have at most {0} selections",
                            maxSelections.Value),
                        new[] { context.MemberName });
                }
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```